# Double click event in subform (Datasheet view) in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a sub form. I want to create a double click event on its record to show its detailed view.

I am not able to see 'Double click' event for the subform. Someone pls help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822517%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: the sub form control has only two events 'On Enter' and 'On Exit'. Also, the sub form - form properties has double click. But that event is working on entire form. In that case, if I double click inside cell, its not accepting the double click. It allows me to double click  outside the cells.

Comment: Inside the cells you have to use the events of these. Choose a cell (e.g. the ID) and put the action in there or, if you must, in all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the subform in design mode.
Select the form properties.
Add a double click event to the form with your procedure in it.
Close and save the form.
Re-open the sub form in the main form.
To the left of the data double click the grey box and your event will run.

Comment: Appreciate ur effort to answer an old question. Cheers!